# Wordpress current menu id

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get the current menuid. I see many solutions where pageid is being used, but this doesn't work when there are more than 1 menu-item linking to the same page. As far as I can see §wp_query gives me page-id, not menu-id.

Does anybody have an idea what to do?

Comment: add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpse_wp_nav_menu_objects' );
function wpse_nav_menu_objects( $sorted_menu_items )
{
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( $menu_item->current ) {
          echo  $menu_item->title;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $sorted_menu_items;
}

Comment: This stoppes at the first item that links to particular page, what if 2 menu-items link to the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter to wp_nav_menu_objects,

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'mwilson123_wp_nav_menu_objects' );
function mwilson123_wp_nav_menu_objects( $menu_items )
{
    foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( $menu_item->current ) {
            $GLOBALS['mwilson123_id'] = $menu_item->ID;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $sorted_menu_items;
}
```

Now you can use this global variable `$GLOBALS['mwilson123_id']` where ever you need.

Comment: first of, arn't you suppose to return $menu_items instead of $sorted_menu_items?